# Why do I get a segmentation fault?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

When I comment out the parts where it has to write to files everything works

```
if((fu=fopen("lista.txt","r")))
    {
        while( fscanf(fu,"%s %s %s %llu %f %f %d",e.ime, e.prezime,e.roditelj,&e.JMBG,&e.visina,&e.tezina,&e.godine) != EOF)
        {
            insertBack(&head,&tail,e);
        }
        ispisLista(head,tail);
        printf("\b");
    }

    fclose(fu);
```

this is the code

http://codepad.org/LKWZDIFT

EDIT: I fixed it by making a file "lista.txt" in the folder of the source code and everything worked!

Comment: Don't put an url in your question? but put the relevant code. compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). Then **use the debugger** (`gdb`)

Comment: Please, post the relevant code here. Your priogram is long. Isolate where the segmentation fault happens (e.g. in a debugger), reduce the program to a small compilable example that reproduces the error.

Comment: You need to provide much more information before we can help you. First off, please add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Don't post all 500 lines of code. Also, give us information about *where* your segfault is occurring. Pointing out the exact line would be preferable.

Comment: @JasonBaker the program compiles, but I cant start it

Comment: Also, please compile with warnings. (I reckon that you develop outside codepad.) If your functions have no meaningful return value, make them void. A possible segmentation violation occurs when you try to `flose(fu)`outside the block where it is assured to be non-null in `main`. Your program should print an error message if the file must be read.

Comment: @KokNikol As Mr. 32 says in his answer, running your code through [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) can be helpful in determing the source of memory errors

Comment: In your code, `q` isn't initialised, so you can't defererence it with `*` or `->`. If you want to swap the nodes' contents, just use a local variable of the `struct element` type.

Comment: @MOehm I did just that and it worked. 

"A possible segmentation violation occurs when you try to flose(fu)outside the block where it is assured to be non-null in main. " can you explain this please? (I posted in the edit how I have fixed it)

Comment: The `fclose(fu)` goes inside the curly braces as last statement. Otherwise, you call `fclose` on `NULL`, which gives undefined behaviour, possibly a segmentation violation. In other words: All code that works on `fu` must go inside the block where it is clear that `fu` is not `NULL`.

Comment: @MOehm I fixed it by making a *.txt file in the folder where the source code is. It works even if the lista.txt is empty

Comment: Yes, but it fails when you can't open that file for whatever reason, i.e. when `fopen` returns `NULL`. Your program should handle such cases gracefully with an error message, not by crashing. (I know your program isn't meant for publication, but you should make a habit of checking such basic things. You'll be glad you did later on.)

Answer (score 0):

You are running that code on codepad.org then it will surely gives you crash. Because it does not support all file i/o and user input related things.

On desktop environment if it gives crash then use **debugger**

**valgrind** is best tool for such cases.

still you can not make it 
then

post the relevant part of the code in which you have problem.